# Flutter | How can I send an audio file to a socket server?

Tags: flutter, socket.io

I'm using flutter_sound plugin for recording an audio, it encodes the audio and retrieve the audio file path, what should I do next in order to get this audio file information an then send it to a socket server?

I'm using socket_io_client plugin for the socket server, I created local socket server for simple chat application and I need to implement voice-messaging

Comment: an obvious solution would be to encode the audio to base64 and send it as plaintext, did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to upload it your server using an API or FTP service. Then pass the file url through socket. The receiver should download files at their end and use it.

You can do the same logic for image and video as-well. You can use some json structure to keep track of different types of messages and update your UI based on that, something like:

```
{
   "type": "audio", // can use text, video, image for respective types
   "data": "url to audio file" // for text type can include the text here
}
```